# Xcode 4.2.1 UIScrollViews not scrolling in storyboard

Tags: xcode, ios5, xcode4.2, storyboard

So basically I have this project, where I have 4 different tab bar pages. 2 of them uses navigation controller & tab bar, and 2 are just view controllers. Now there is this one viewcontroller, which I need to add a scroll view to. So basically, I click on the item in the tab bar, it takes me to a view controller, where I can scroll down and up. I have been following [Youtube Video Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mws6Zbq_y6c), but I do not get it to work. The problem is that I use the exact code, and I change the ViewController class to the .h and .m name (ScrollViewViewController), and I put in a scroll view that has 320 x 1000, and a button at the top, but it doesn't scroll! How can I solve this problem?

Note: That if you don't know my problem, but could very detailed walk me through on how to add a scroll view to storyboards in xcode 4.2, then that would be amazing :)!

scrollerViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

scrollerViewController.h

```
@interface scrollerViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
}
@end
```

And here comes a picture of the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: I also have the same issue.
I follow the same tutorial, but I didn't manage to link the ScrollView with the outlet (youtube video - 5:00). There is no "File's Owner" or "Scroll" in the Outelts section.
How did you link the ScrollView without this outlet ?

Answer (score 0):

I need some of the code in order to really know your problem, but let me throw in my guess. You may be setting the size 320x1000 to the frame size of the scrollview by any chance? The frame size of the scrollview has to stay 320x480, and the contentSize should be 320x1000. Sorry if it was a wrong guess, but shouldn't do any harm :)

Something like this in your ViewController of the scrollView...

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      UIScrollView * scrollView = self.view;
      scrollView.frame = (CGRect){scrollView.frame.origin, CGSizeMake(320, 480)};
      scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
      scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // I am setting the white background, so that the scroll indicator is visible
}
```

I am assuming you are setting ScrollView as the top view of the ViewController in your Storyboard as in the attached image.

[image: Screenshot of the storyboard]

Comment: Hey! I added the code to the main err title. So please check it out! Thanks a ton :)!

Comment: The code looks okay. Several things I would check are

- Whether `scroller` is properly bound to the IBOutlet. You can check this in Connections Inspector in Interface Builder. Your 'scroller' should be connected to 'Scroll View' in 'Outlets' section.
- Whether `scroller's` frame is set properly (e.g., (0, 0, 320, 480) ). You can check this with NSLog too.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the exact same movie and it did not work for me either. But this movie did: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBlwepYK7Zs

I followed that one and now i got it to work.

A bit late but might be more people looking for a solution to this.